# Jupyter not working in VSCode Virtual Envirronemnt

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am new to jupyter and right from start I am trying to run it in VSCode and that too with a virtual environment. I hope that is not too much for you guys.
So here are steps I did;

> I installed python and vscode
> Added Paths in windows and all virtual environment things work fine
> For data processing I created new virtual environment 'DataProcessingVenv'
> I opened this venv in Terminal in VSCode and installed Pandas
> I did pip install Jupyter
> I did pip install ipykernel
> next did ipython kernel install --user --name=DataProcessingVenv
> In VSCode I created new notebook
> pressed Ctrl+Shift+P and selected interpreter as /DataProcessingVenv/Scripts/Python.exe

Now I am trying to read a csv present in same fodler where notebook is present but somehow it is not working. I really don't know what is wrong and where, even don't know if I have provided all required info to solve the issue. Please guide me it some more info is required or if I can do something to solve the issue. I am attaching the current image in VSCode with error at the end.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So at the end the solution was simple. But it took time to learn. I just had to run all previous cells in Jupyter to make the current cell work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).